# How can I get line number by marks in nvim?

Tags: neovim

I want to get the line number by a mark, is it possible to do it in nvim in Lua? I have searched the doc for mark but I cannot find anything useful.

https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua.html

Comment: why not using vimscript functions `line()` and `getpos()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`:h nvim_buf_get_mark()`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#nvim_buf_get_mark%28%29) line this:

```
local r, c = unpack(vim.api.nvim_buf_get_mark(0, "a"))
print(string.format("row: [%d], col: [%d]", r, c))
```

The first argument is the reference to the buffer (`0` is the current buffer) and the second argument is the name of the mark.

Comment: Thank you @statox!